# How do I write a .pro file(used by QT) to compile pybind11 related c++ code?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qmake, pybind11

I actually have a C++ project that is setup in QT Creator and has a `.pro` file.
I would like to write python bindings for some of its functions and import them in python.
I am trying to use pybind11.
I am on Windows.

But I don't know how to write pybind11 related stuff in `.pro` file.
I was able to include pybind and python header files and python libs, but I don't know how to setup target file to be generated so that it can be used in python. Everywhere I only find cmake examples.

Comment: FYI: You can use CMake with qtcreator just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using qmake:

```
TARGET = NameOfYourPythonModule
TEMPLATE = lib

HEADERS += *.h
SOURCES += *.cpp

INCLUDEPATH +=  location/of/python/include \
                location/of/pybind11/include

LIBS += -Llocation/of/python/libs \
        -lpython$${yourPythonVersionHere}$${debugExtensionHere}
```

That should get you started. This should build a file named `NameOfYourPythonModule.dll` on windows, which you can import into python. If you find you cannot import it, you may need to manually change the extension, so that the file name reads:
`NameOfYourPythonModule.pyd`.
Any problems or questions let me know

Comment: Thanks! I will check this when I get time. Right now I actually converted everything to CMakeLists.txt as lot more support is available